# Apache reload mid request

Tags: apache, perl, httprequest, restart

I need a request to reload the server and use the updated source without the user having to intervene.

As it stands, I ping the server with a request to update source using git. I reload Apache to flush INC/conf files (I'm aware the current request hasn't been flushed). To prevent the user from having to interact, I return a silent JSON to the client with details needed to continue. The client script then POSTs back to the server. Problem is, the second request is run with the previous source. Shouldn't it be a new request of the updated parent process?

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webserver is most likely asking the client to cache by setting http headers in its response